# how to loop through global and sub object to find a match with this keyword in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm to create a function that will loop through all objects to find a match with this keyword in understanding a JavaScript code?

Started out like this:

```
function valueOfTHis (this) {

    for(var thisObject in window) {
        if(thisObject === "object" && this === "thisObject") {    
            console.log("match found for this keyword: "+ thisObject);
        }                                     
    }
}
```

How do I check sub sub sub objects of window object for a match against this keyword?

Comment: Whatever you think you're doing with this code, stop it. It's wrong.

Comment: What are you asking? I can't understand your question.

Comment: I think they want a recursive search on property name by string starting on the `window` object?

Comment: I'm trying to find out which object the this keyword is reference to

Comment: this refers to window in your scope.

Comment: You are right @Darko Z

Comment: Seriously people can you please close this question? "Unclear what you're asking." There's 5 people complaining about how it's unclear and only 1 close vote.

Comment: @djechlin why close if the asker is active and willing to help explain. Not everyone is a native English speaker here.

Comment: @YetA-beyene it might also help if you put in an example or two of input and expected output

Comment: What so difficult about the question? How do you find the value of this keyword? Or which object it is associated with?

Comment: @Ibu—in the OP, the use of *this* as a formal parameter is a syntax error, as *this* is a [*reserved word*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6.1).

Comment: @DarkoZ for many many many reasons explained throughout meta.SO and this has nothing to do with being a native English speaker. The *code* itself is gibberish in the language of Javascript, not English, and what little information is presented in English I understood just fine.

Comment: @DarkoZ further more we changed the language to "on hold" so the OP can improve after the question is put on hold, but it should not be answered in the meantime because it cannot be answered in the meantime. See my 2 downvotes below for good proof that questions that should be closed should not be answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code:

```
function(this) {
```

If the keyword *function* appears as the first token in a statement, it represents the start of a function declaration and must be followed by a valid identifier that is the function's name, so:

```
function myFunc(...) {
```

You can't use *this* in a parameter list, it's a [keyword](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6.1.1) which makes it a [reserved word](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6.1) and not a valid identifier. If you're looking to pass in an identifier and search for it on the window (global) object and sub–objects, then you might try:

```
function myFunc(name) {

    // If not set by the call, this will be the global object (window in a browser)
    // but will remain undefined in strict mode
    var thisObj = this;

    // For every enumerable property of thisObj
    for (var key in thisObj) {

        // Does name match property name?
        if (name == key) {
            console.log('Match found for ' + name + ': ' + thisObj[key]);
        }

        // If property is an object, search it too
        // Set this to the object in the call
        if (typeof thisObj[key] == 'object') {
            console.log(thisObj[key]);

              // Recursively call the function. This may take a very long time,
              // uncomment at your own risk
              // myFunc.call(thisObj[key], name);
        }

    }
}

myFunc('alert');
```

This will find matching enmuerable properties called *name* on the global object and it's child objects. In strict mode, you'll need to call it like:

```
myFunc.call(this, name);
```

to make sure *this* is set correctly in the first call.

Comment: thanks a lot Rob for understanding my confusing question enough to provide a solution

Comment: thanks for the learning moment, I didn't know this keyword can't be used as a parameter of a function and it makes sense that it can't